# Clojure re-find works but re-matcher fails for the same string-pattern combination

Tags: regex, clojure, regex-group

Why does clojure's `re-matcher` fail for the same string-pattern combo that `re-find` works for?

Regex Pattern: `#"\[(?<level>[A-Z]*)\]:\s(?<msg>.*)"`

Example String: `[WARNING]:   \tTimezone not set  \r\n`

Below is an example on the console with above pattern & string and another string that works with both `re-find` and `re-matcher` (with the same pattern).

```
user=> (def s1 "[ERROR]: This is an error.")
#'user/s1
user=> (def s2 "[WARNING]:   \tTimezone not set  \r\n")
#'user/s2
user=> (def rx #"\[(?<level>[A-Z]*)\]:\s(?<msg>.*)")
#'user/rx


user=> (re-find rx s1)
["[ERROR]: This is an error." "ERROR" "This is an error."]
user=> (re-find rx s2)
["[WARNING]:   \tTimezone not set  " "WARNING" "  \tTimezone not set  "]


user=> (def m1 (re-matcher rx s1))
#'user/m1
user=> (def m2 (re-matcher rx s2))
#'user/m2

user=> (.matches m1)
true
user=> (.matches m2)
false
```

As you can see from the code snippet, `re-find` works on string `s2`, however `re-matcher`'s `matches` method returns `false` for the same string-pattern combination.

I read that `re-find` uses the `Matcher` methods behind the scenes ([ref](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/re-find)), so what am I missing here?

Comment: `.matches` requires a full string match, but `.` does not match line breaks. You need to add `(?s)` at the start of the pattern, or use something like `(?<msg>(?s:.*))`.

Comment: The "duplicate" is a Java question, but this question is in regards to Clojure.  Sure, the two may be related, but surely it is a separate question — people looking for how Clojure deals with regular expressions won't necessarily look for Java answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```clj
user> (def s1 "[ERROR]: This is an error.")
#'user/s1
user> (def s2 "[WARNING]:   \tTimezone not set  \r\n")
#'user/s2
user> (def rx #"\[(?<level>[A-Z]*)\]:\s(?<msg>(?s:.)*)")
#'user/rx
user> (re-find rx s1)
["[ERROR]: This is an error." "ERROR" "This is an error."]
user> (re-find rx s2)
["[WARNING]:   \tTimezone not set  \r\n"
 "WARNING"
 "  \tTimezone not set  \r\n"]
user> (def m1 (re-matcher rx s1))
#'user/m1
user> (def m2 (re-matcher rx s2))
#'user/m2
user> (.matches m1)
true
user> (.matches m2)
true
user> (re-groups m2)
["[WARNING]:   \tTimezone not set  \r\n"
 "WARNING"
 "  \tTimezone not set  \r\n"]
```

As Wiktor has pointed out, the `.` in the regex does not match the EOL (end-of-line) markers; and `re-find` finds any substring match, whereas `.matches` on `re-matcher` requires a full string match.  So, if you use `(?s:....)` to enable "single-line mode" you get the regex that does what you intended.  See the regex change above.

But note that this regex includes the EOL chars in the `<msg>` group. If you do not want to include the EOL chars in the `<msg>` group, then change the regex to

```clj
user> (def rx1 #"\[(?<level>[A-Z]*)\]:\s(?<msg>.*)(?s:.*)")
#'user/rx1
user> (re-find rx1 s1)
["[ERROR]: This is an error." "ERROR" "This is an error."]
user> (re-find rx1 s2)
["[WARNING]:   \tTimezone not set  \r\n"
 "WARNING"
 "  \tTimezone not set  "]
user> (def m3 (re-matcher rx1 s1))
#'user/m3
user> (def m4 (re-matcher rx1 s2))
#'user/m4
user> (.matches m3)
true
user> (.matches m4)
true
user> (re-groups m4)
["[WARNING]:   \tTimezone not set  \r\n"
 "WARNING"
 "  \tTimezone not set  "]
```